# Magento 2 all product and category request is redirect to http://baseurl/20us%20search%20us%20search%20us%20search?amnoroute

Tags: magento2.4, redirect, docker

I have set up my live project in a docker environment using this.

> https://github.com/bhaveshpp/magento-docker-server/

All thing working perfect but when I search for the product it will redirect my request to

`http://baseurl/20us%20search%20us%20search%20us%20search?amnoroute`

%20search is adding to URL and `This page isn’t working ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error is thrown.

I have run all the commands

```
setup:upgrade
setup:di:compile
setup:static-contand:deployed
indexer:reindex
cache:flush
```

and all commands are run successfully.

Has anyone faced this issue before?
If anyone has a suggestion or solution then please add your answer here.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue.

We have installed amasty advanced search module which redirects the 404 pages to the catalog search page, and also change the default route with 'search' text.

I found that `web/unsecure/base_link_url`  and `web/secure/base_link_url` was `HTTP://baseurl/us/` So search form action URL become `http://baseurl/us/catalogsearch/result` so it was redirecting to 404 page and amasty Xsearch redirect it to catalog search page and catalog search page URL is wrong so it again redirects this page to 404 page and that's while the recursive call was the reason behind this issue.